# How to use gridfs with the mongo-cxx-driver

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I want to use the mongo-cxx-driver in my application, but I can't find a way to use the gridfs feature of mongodb.
I think the current stable version of the mongodb-cxx-driver (3.0.2) still doesn't support gridfs and I have to use the mongo-c-driver for that. Is that right?
In case that is right, is there a way to use the current connection of the mongo-cxx-driver (because the cxx is only a wrapper of the c client) to use the API of the mongo-c-driver to use gridfs features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the mongo C++11 driver does not yet support GridFS but it's coming.

See issue [CXX-1130: Implement GridFS spec](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-1130), the linked implementation user stories and the proposed [spec](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst).